# gpg expiration TIME?

Tags: gpg

I have a licence that I'm signing with:

```
gpg --default-sig-expire "2024-02-14" --sign licence
```

This results in:

```
$ gpg --verify licence.gpg
gpg: Signature made Tue 13 Feb 2024 08:18:39 AM CET
gpg:                using RSA key 1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF
gpg:                issuer "stew@unix.stackexchange.com"
gpg: Good signature from "Stewart <stew@unix.stackexchange.com>" [ultimate]
gpg: Signature expires Wed 14 Feb 2024 12:00:00 PM CET
```

The `12:00:00 PM CET` is my problem.  I'm usually going for lunch at that time.  I'd rather not get phone calls about systems going offline while I'm at lunch.  Is it possible to specify the time?  I'd rather it expired at `13:00:00 PM CET`.

---

`--ask-sig-expire` only prompts you for the number of days/weeks/years:

```
$ gpg --ask-sig-expire --sign licence
Please specify how long the signature should be valid.
         0 = signature does not expire
      <n>  = signature expires in n days
      <n>w = signature expires in n weeks
      <n>m = signature expires in n months
      <n>y = signature expires in n years
Signature is valid for? (0)
```

ISO 8601 doesn't seem supported:

```
$ gpg --default-sig-expore "2024-02-14T13:00:00+02:00" --sign licence
gpg: '2024-02-14T13:00:00+02:00' is not a valid signature expiration
```

The `man systemd.time` specification doesn't seem supported

```
$ gpg --default-sig-expire "2024-02-14 13:00:00" --sign licence
gpg: '2024-02-14 13:00:00' is not a valid signature expiration
```

The man page also doesn't suggest that a time is possible:

```
--default-sig-expire
       The default expiration time to use for signature expiration. Valid values 
       are "0" for no expiration, a number followed by the letter d (for days), 
       w (for weeks), m (for months), or  y (for years) (for example "2m" for two 
       months, or "5y" for five years), or an absolute date in the form 
       YYYY-MM-DD. Defaults to "0".
```

---

The only solution I've found, is to change my system's time zone to the next timezone west of me, then sign, then set my system's time zone back to my original time.

```
$ sudo mv /etc/localtime{,.backup} 
$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
$ gpg --default-sig-expire "2024-02-14" --sign licence
$ sudo mv /etc/localtime{.backup,}
$ gpg --verify licence.gpg
gpg: Signature made Tue 13 Feb 2024 08:18:39 AM CET
gpg:                using RSA key 1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF
gpg:                issuer "stew@unix.stackexchange.com"
gpg: Good signature from "Stewart <stew@unix.stackexchange.com>" [ultimate]
gpg: Signature expires Wed 14 Feb 2024 01:00:05 PM CET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only format accepted by `--default-sig-expire` with a time specification is `YYYYMMddTHHmmss[Z]`:

```
gpg --default-sig-expire 20240214T130000 --sign license
```

Any timezone specifier is ignored, and daylight savings time is ignored too; so currently in Europe this produces an expiration time one hour later than the time specified. Processing time also affects the ultimate signature expiry; for example, if `gpg` prompts for anything (*e.g.* to confirm overwriting an existing signed file), the incurred delay pushes the expiration back.

To check this, look for [the `--default-sig-expire` definition](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=g10/gpg.c;h=96a0c345cac9e093fa0703703722d46110a79d5c;hb=dfa60c09f5cd992515df5fdb275dbee7f8f23b71#l670), then determine that [the option’s value is parsed using `parse_expire_string`](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=g10/gpg.c;h=96a0c345cac9e093fa0703703722d46110a79d5c;hb=dfa60c09f5cd992515df5fdb275dbee7f8f23b71#l3193), [which knows about a number of formats](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=g10/keygen.c;h=c98deb635e8c0bacdffee48273955ff309339e0c;hb=dfa60c09f5cd992515df5fdb275dbee7f8f23b71#l2826). The only one of those which accepts an absolute timestamp including hours, minutes, and seconds, is [`isotime2epoch`](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=common/gettime.c;h=136c47ca7739cdd8a688f2c626da51d930c0a3fd;hb=dfa60c09f5cd992515df5fdb275dbee7f8f23b71#l545) (and its 64-bit `time_t` variant), with a comment specifying

> The only supported format is "yyyymmddThhmmss[Z]" delimited by white space, nul, a colon or a comma.

Comment: Yes, that works!  But how did you know that?  Is this just an experience thing, or did I miss something in the man page?

Comment: I read the source code ;-).

Comment: Wow!  That would have been my next step but I thought it was overkill.  Very nice.

Comment: "Processing time also affects the ultimate signature expiry".  That explains why my keys are often off by 2-5 seconds!